# How to change leaderboard icon in Game Center (iOS)?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

I made a Unity iOS gaming app and implemented a Game Center leaderboard. How can I change the default icon of the leaderboard? On the iTunes Connect/App Store Connect page it seems not to be possible. Is it maybe done in XCode?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It‘s in App Store Connect, where you setup the leaderboards.

Comment: @JeanLuc I cannot see any leaderboard setting at the App Store Connect page. Only In-App-Purchase references. The Leaderboards are handled over iTunes Connect I thought? Can you send me a screenshot where the settings appear? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is complete selection path to add an image to a leaderboard:**
My Apps > App X > Features > Game Center > Leaderboards > Leaderboard X > Leaderboard Localization > Language X > Image (optional) > Choose File

Here is a **screenshot** where Game Center is located in [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) (previously named iTunes Connect):

[image: Screenshot of Game Center location in App Store Connect]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! This is the right solution.